# Numerical boundary-finding algorithms

Tags: numerical-methods, implicit-function

I'm very familiar with [numerical root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) like Brent's method ([`scipy.optimize.brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html)) or [Chandrupatla's method](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/855.php). What if I am looking for a boundary numerically?

Suppose for example that I have an unknown monotonically increasing function $y = g(x)$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ as represented by the boundary of some region $f(x,y) \ge 0$.

I cannot evaluate $g(x)$ directly; instead, I can evaluate $f(x,y)$ and compare it to zero. For any fixed value of $x=x_0$ I can use a root-finding method to determine $y$ such that $f(x_0,y)=0$.

Aside from sweeping across the interval $x\in[a,b]$ and repeating a root-finding method for each value of $x$, is there a more efficient way? (Suppose I know that $g(x)$ is continuous, for example, and that its derivative $dg/dx$ is "mostly" continuous; then the solution to $y=g(x_0+\Delta x)$ is close to $y=g(x_0)$ .)

Comment: So you want to find an $x$ so that $f(x,0)=0$? This is again a scalar root finding task. Or is the complication that you also want to ensure that $y\mapso f(x,y)$ has positive values close to $y=0$?

Comment: No, for *each* value of $x_0$ in an interval (example: "covering" the interval numerically with, say, 10000 points), I want to find the value of $y$ such that $f(x_0,y)=0$, and I want to know if there is a more efficient method than independently using a root-finding method, by using continuity.

Comment: I have a related question where I have a boolean function $f(x,y) \in {0,1}$, and $f(x_0,y) = 0$ for $y < g(x_0)$, $f(x_0,y) = 1$ for $y \ge g(x_0)$, but I have no way of evaluating $g(x)$ directly. (In this case, it seems like I have to use bisection rather than one of the faster root-finding methods.) But I wanted to start with the non-boolean case.

Comment: This is similar to edge following algorithms in image processing or contour construction algorithms in plotting. For the last there is even a catchy name, "box-something". Take a compass rose of points around the current $(x,y)$ and determine where the boundary curve goes. Or from another p.o.v., if you have a semi-reduced bracketing interval for the current $x$, then it or some modest extension will be a bracketing interval for the next $x$. If derivatives exist or are known, one can make that even more systematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $g$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with Lipschitz constant $K$, then

$$g(x)-K\Delta\le g(x+\Delta)\le g(x)+K\Delta x\tag1$$

will provide reasonably tight bounds if $\Delta$ is sufficiently small.

If you know that $g$ is differentiable, then the first order Taylor

$$g(x+\Delta)=g(x)+g'(x)\Delta+o(\Delta)\tag2$$

is an even better estimate. This may be supplemented into the above bounds to give even faster convergence, or extended further if more derivatives are known.

If $K$ is unknown, then it may suffice to use an initial estimate $\tilde K>0$. Whenever $(1)$ fails to hold, double $\tilde K$ and try again. Another simple alternative strategy if $\Delta x$ is always very small would be to use $\tilde K=k|g'(x)|$ for some $k>1$.

If $g'(x)$ is unknown, then it may suffice to instead use a finite difference estimate in its place from the last two points. Higher order estimates can of course be derived by using more points too.

If $g$ is continuously twice differentiable then we actually know the error of $(2)$ to be bounded by $L\Delta^2$ for some $L>0$, even if you replace $g'(x)$ by an estimate with $\mathcal O(\Delta)$ error. Following a similar situation as with $K$ and $(1)$, you could extend $(2)$ to give the bounds

$$g(x)+g'(x)\Delta x-L\Delta^2\le g(x+\Delta)\le g(x)+g'(x)\Delta x+L\Delta^2\tag3$$

and so on for higher order derivatives. Analogously, such an $L$ may be estimated in the same ways as $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are *very* weak. If stronger assumptions are made, then I can see the some options.

If $f = f(x,y)$ is differentiable, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(x)) \not =0$, and $g$ is differentiable, then $g$ satisfies the ordinary differential equation
$$ g'(x) = - \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x))}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(x))}$$
Why? By the definition of $g$ we have $$\phi(x) = f(x,g(x)) = 0.$$ By the chain rule we have
$$0 = \phi'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x)) +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(x)) g'(x).$$
In principle, you can then recover $g$ using your favorite numerical method for solving ODEs. However, without some form of stabilization we will move away from the true solution. Instead, you can use the known value of $g(x)$ and the ODE to generate two *different* approximations of $g(x + h)$. Ex. You could use $1$ step of Euler's explicit method with stepsize $h$ to produce the $y_0 \approx g(x+h)$ and $2$ steps of Euler's explicit method with stepsize $\frac{1}{2}h$ to produce $y_1 \approx g(x+h)$. It is unlikely that $y_0 = y_1$. You can then use the secant method to solve
$$f(x+h,y) = 0$$
using $y_0$ and $y_1$ to initialize the search for the solution $y=g(x+h)$.

In the above analysis I do not see any good ways to exploit the assumption that $g$ is assumed to be increasing. It is mildly helpful to know that $g(x) \leq y = g(x+h)$, so that $g(x)$ is can be be used to bound $y$ from below, but I also need an upper bound for $y$ before I can use a safe method such as bisection to solve for $y$.

If we are only willing to assume that $g$ is differentiable, then I would slide from $g(x)$ and $g(x-h)$ to an approximation of $g(x+h)$ using linear extrapolation, i.e.
$$ g(x+h) \approx 2 g(x) - g(x-h).$$
I would use the secant method to solve $f(x,+h,y)=0$ with $y_0 = g(x)$ and $y_1 = 2g(x) - g(x-h)$. In this setting it is (mildly) useful to know that $g$ is strictly increasing. We would then be certain that $y_0 \not = y_1$ and it would be possible to do at least one secant step.

---

I would be interested to know to what extent you can strengthen your assumptions on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Unfortunately per the comments it seems $f$ is not differentiable but rather discrete, which explains the weak assumptions used.